# How to open specific View in SwiftUI app using AppIntents

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm very new to Intents in Swift. Using the [Dive Into App Intents](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10032/) video from WWDC 22 and the [Booky](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky) example app, I've gotten my app to show up in the Shortcuts app and show an initial shortcut which opens the app to the main view. Here is the `AppIntents` code:

```
import AppIntents

enum NavigationType: String, AppEnum, CaseDisplayRepresentable {
    case folders
    case cards
    case favorites

    // This will be displayed as the title of the menu shown when picking from the options
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "Navigation")
    
    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [Self:DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .folders: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Folders"),
        .cards: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Card Gallery"),
        .favorites: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Favorites")
    ]
}

struct OpenCards: AppIntent {
    
    // Title of the action in the Shortcuts app
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open Card Gallery"
    // Description of the action in the Shortcuts app
    static var description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("This action will open the Card gallery in the Hello There app.", categoryName: "Navigation")
    // This opens the host app when the action is run
    static var openAppWhenRun = true
    
    @Parameter(title: "Navigation")
    var navigation: NavigationType

    @MainActor // <-- include if the code needs to be run on the main thread
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
                ViewModel.shared.navigateToGallery()
            return .result()
    }
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Open \(\.$navigation)")
    }
    
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = ViewModel()
    
    @Published var path: any View = FavoritesView()
    
    // Clears the navigation stack and returns home
    func navigateToGallery() {
        path = FavoritesView()
    }
}
```

Right now, the Shortcut lets you select one of the enums (Folders, Cards, and Favorites), but always launches to the root of the app. Essentially no different then just telling Siri to open my app. My app uses a `TabView` in its ContentView with TabItems for the related Views:

```
            .tabItem {
                Text("Folders")
                Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
            }
            NavigationView {
                GalleryView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Cards")
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.portrait.on.rectangle.portrait.angled.fill")
            }
            NavigationView {
                FavoritesView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Favs")
                Image(systemName: "star.square.on.square.fill")
            }
            NavigationView {
                SettingsView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Settings")
                Image(systemName: "gear")
            }
```

How can I configure the AppIntents above to include something like "Open Favorites View" and have it launch into that TabItem view? I think the `ViewModel` needs tweaking... I've tried to configure it to open the `FavoritesView()` by default, but I'm lost on the proper path forward.

Thanks!

[EDIT -- updated with current code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need some way to do programmatic navigation.

With `TabView`, you can do that by passing a `selection` argument, a binding that you can then update to select a tab. An enum of all your tabs works nicely here. Here's an example view:

```
struct SelectableTabView: View {
    enum Tabs {
        case first, second
    }
    
    @State var selected = Tabs.first
    
    var body: some View {
        // selected will track the current tab:
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            Text("First tab content")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                }
                // The tag is how TabView knows which tab is which:
                .tag(Tabs.first)

            VStack {
                Text("Second tab content")
                
                Button("Select first tab") {
                    // You can change selected to navigate to a different tab:
                    selected = .first
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.second)
        }
    }
}
```

So in your code, ViewModel.path could be an enum representing the available tabs, and you could pass a binding to path (`$viewModel.path`) to your `TabView`. Then you could simply set `path = .favorites` to navigate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always get Bindings backward. Does the @Binding go in ContentView or the ViewModel? If I put it in the ViewModel I get "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: You should have a reference to your view model as an `@ObservedObject` in your view. Then you can create bindings out of its `@Published` properties by doing something like this: `$model.path`

Comment: Ok, I've got my enum

enum Page {
    case folders, cards, favs
}

And I've got my ViewModel:

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //@State var selected = Page.folders
    
    static let shared = ViewModel()
    @Published var path: Page = .folders
    
    // configure nav
    func navigateToFolders() {
        path = .folders
    }
    func navigateToFavs() {
        path = .favs
    }
    func navigateToCards() {
        path = .cards
    }
}

And in ContentView: (at)ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
and also TabView(selection: $viewModel.path)

Comment: And added the below to the AppIntents

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        if ViewModel.shared.path == .favs {
            ViewModel.shared.navigateToFavs()
        }
        if ViewModel.shared.path == .cards {
            ViewModel.shared.navigateToCards()
        }
        if ViewModel.shared.path == .folders {
            ViewModel.shared.navigateToFolders()
        }
            return .result()
    }

Comment: I'm convinced your answer is correct @asyncawait so I will accept it as the answer, though I haven't been able to successfully implement it yet.

Comment: It's hard to read the code in comments - where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey thanks for the followup! Yeah the comments make it tough! At this point the app shows everything as expected in the Shortcuts app... however it still only opens up to the launch view, even when I select "Favorites" or "Card Gallery". I’m not sure what my code is missing. Here are some pastebin links that should make it easier ////

  AppIntents.swift: https://pastebin.com/1GNysi7Z  //// 
ViewModel.swift: https://pastebin.com/BHNSy7KV //// 
Helper.swift: https://pastebin.com/RqWt6qzC

Comment: Oh, forgot my ContentView.swift: https://pastebin.com/n1tNChrM

Comment: Sounds like you're very close. If I were in your shoes, next thing I'd do would be to run the app with the debugger attached (i.e. just Product > Run in Xcode) and verify two things. First, does the programmatic nav work? Make a temporary button in the app that changes `path`, or set a breakpoint and just change it in the debugger (`e ViewModel.shared.path = .favs` or similar). Once that works, is your intent doing the right thing? Set a breakpoint in the func that changes `path`, make your intent run and check that it hits the breakpoint. If that all happens... it should work?

Comment: I read through your pastes... looks like your problem might be different instances of your view model. If the intent uses `ViewModel.shared`, and the view uses `ViewModel()` (a different instance), that's not going to work. You need to change the state of the same instance the View is observing.

Comment: Good catch! I changed the ObservedObject to @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel.shared but same behavior. I'll keep poking at it!

Comment: I added a button that set ViewModel.shared.path to .favs and it worked! So it's something in the AppIntent I believe. Digging...

Comment: Got it! my func perform() in AppIntent needed to reference 'navigation' being == to the enum, instead of ViewModel.shared... Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [Accelerating app interactions with App Intents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/acceleratingappinteractionswithappintents) sample code, the right way to do this appears to be through the use of dependencies, namele the [`@Dependency`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/appdependency) property wrapper and the [`AppDependencyManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/appdependencymanager) class:

The implementation for `NavigationModel` looks like this:

```swift
/// An observable object that manages the selection events for `NavigationSplitView`.
@MainActor
@Observable class NavigationModel {

    /// The selected item in `SidebarColumn`.
    var selectedCollection: TrailCollection?
    
    /// The selected item in the `NavigationSplitView` content view.
    var selectedTrail: Trail?
    
    /// The column visibility in the `NavigationSplitView`.
    var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility
    
    /// The visibility of a sheet when an activity is active.
    var displayInProgressActivityInfo = false
    
    init(selectedCollection: TrailCollection? = nil, columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all) {
        self.selectedCollection = selectedCollection
        self.columnVisibility = columnVisibility
    }
}
```

The navigation model uses `TrailCollection` objects. I won't put their implementation here because it's not very relevant and I don't want to have an answer with so much code.

Then you register the dependency in your `App`'s `init()` method:

```swift
struct AppIntentsSampleApp: App {
    init() {
        // ...
        let trailDataManager = TrailDataManager.shared
        trailManager = trailDataManager
        
        let navigationModel = NavigationModel(selectedCollection: trailDataManager.nearMeCollection)
        sceneNavigationModel = navigationModel
        // ...
        AppDependencyManager.shared.add(dependency: navigationModel)
        // ,,,
    }
}
```

The sample app provides a `OpenFavorites` intent. This is where you register your dependency:

```
struct OpenFavorites: AppIntent {
    // ...
    @Dependency
    private var navigationModel: NavigationModel
    // ...
    // We also need the trailManager
    @Dependency
    private var trailManager: TrailDataManager
}
```

And then you can simply mutate this navigation model:

```
struct OpenFavorites: AppIntent {
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        navigationModel.selectedCollection = trailManager.favoritesCollection
    return .result()
    }
}
```

So based on your `NavigationType` object, you have the right idea. You just need to turn it into a dependency with the aforementioned APIs and you will have this done (possibly) the Apple way.

I have my reservations about this approach (what if you have a multi-window app where each Window keeps track of its own navigation hierarchy?), but it appears to be the best approach so far.