Swift AppIntents and Shortcuts Do Not Work when Attempting to Navigate to a Different View
I'm struggling to understand how to implement AppIntents and Shortcuts in an iOS app. I am able to add a shortcut for opening the app in the following code as OpenThing.swift. After adding the Shortcut I can tap the Shortcut and open the app and I can activate Siri and open the app. However, with CreateNewThing.swift I have not been able to discover how to open the app and navigate to the ThingAddView. When tapping or speaking, the app opens, but does not navigate to the ThingAddView.
This is a stripped down version of all the code needed to run the app as is:
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


@main
struct ThingIntentNavApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("navigateToThingAddView") private var navigateToThingAddView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ThingListView()
                .onAppear {
                    if dataStore.navigateToThingAddView {
                        dataStore.navigateToThingAddView = false // Reset flag
                    }
                }
        }
        .modelContainer(for: [Thing.self])
    }
    
    init() {
        print(URL.applicationSupportDirectory.path(percentEncoded: false))
        ThingShortcuts.updateAppShortcutParameters()
    }
}

struct ThingShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var shortcutTileColor = ShortcutTileColor.navy
    
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        
            AppShortcut(
                intent: CreateNewThing(),
                phrases: [
                    "Create a new Thing in \(.applicationName)"
                ],
                shortTitle: "Create a Thing",
                systemImageName: "document.badge.plus"
            )
        
            AppShortcut(
                intent: OpenThing(),
                phrases: [
                    "Open Thing in \(.applicationName)"
                ],
                shortTitle: "Open Thing",
                systemImageName: "gear"
            )
        
    }//var
}//thing shortcuts

@Model
class Thing {

    var name: String = ""
    var comment: String = "no comment"
    var recordType: String = "0"
    var count: Int = 0

    init(name: String, comment: String, recordType: String, count: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.comment = comment
        self.recordType = recordType
        self.count = count
    }
    
}//class



struct OpenThing: AppIntent {

    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open Thing"
    
    static var description = IntentDescription("Opens the app.")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        
        return .result()
    }
    
  
}//create new book

struct CreateNewThing: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Create New Thing"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Opens the app and moves to the Add Thing screen.")
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

    @AppStorage("navigateToThingAddView") private var navigateToThingAddView: Bool = false

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        navigateToThingAddView = true

        return .result()
    }
}

@Observable
class DataStore {
    
    static let shared = DataStore()
    
    var navigateToThingAddView: Bool = false
    
    init() {}
    
}//class


struct ThingAddView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var comment: String = ""
    @State private var recordType: String = ""
    @State private var count: Int = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Text("Name:")
                TextField("", text: $name)
                
                Text("Comment:")
                TextField("", text: $comment)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                
                Text("Record Type:")
                TextField("", text: $recordType)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") { dismiss() }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        saveNewThing()
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Save")
                    }
                }
            }//toolbar
            .navigationTitle("Thing Add View")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }//nav
    }//body
    
    private func saveNewThing() {
        
        let newThing = Thing(
            name: name,
            comment: comment,
            recordType: recordType,
            count: count
        )//new thing
        
        context.insert(newThing)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            //dataStore.contextSaveError = "New Book context save failed."
        }
    }//save thing

}//struct

struct ThingDetailView: View {
    
    var selectedThing: Thing?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let t = selectedThing {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Text(t.name)
                    Text(t.comment)
                    Text(t.recordType)
                }
            }
        }//if let
    }//body
}//struct

struct ThingListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @AppStorage("navigateToThingAddView") private var navigateToThingAddView: Bool = false
    
    @Query(sort: \Thing.name) var things: [Thing]
    @State private var selectedThing: Thing?
    
    @State private var showThingAddView: Bool = false
    @State private var dataStore = DataStore.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Things")
                    .font(.title).fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                Spacer()
                
                Menu {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        showThingAddView = true
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Add Thing", systemImage: "plus")
                    })
                    
                } label: {//menu
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }//menu
                .padding(.trailing)
            }//h on top
            
            VStack {
                List(selection: $selectedThing) {
                    ForEach(things) { thing in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ThingDetailView(selectedThing: thing)) {
                            Text(thing.name)
                        }
                    }
                }//list
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showThingAddView) {
                    ThingAddView()
                }
            }//v
            .onAppear {
                if things.isEmpty {
                    createSampleThings()
                }

                if navigateToThingAddView {
                    showThingAddView = true
                    navigateToThingAddView = false // Reset flag
                }
                
            }
        } detail: {
            VStack {
                if selectedThing != nil {
                    ThingDetailView(selectedThing: selectedThing)
                } else {
                    WelcomeView()
                }
            }//v
        }//detail
    }//body
    
    
    //MARK: -  Samples
    
    func createSampleThings() {

        let thing1 = Thing(
            name: "To Kill a Mockingbird",
            comment: "A classic novel set in the American South.",
            recordType: "Harper Lee",
            count: 5
        )
        
        let thing2 = Thing(
            name: "1984",
            comment: "A dystopian novel.",
            recordType: "George Orwell",
            count: 4
        )
        
        let thing3 = Thing(
            name: "The Great Gatsby",
            comment: "A novel about the American Dream.",
            recordType: "F. Scott Fitzgerald",
            count: 4
        )
        
        let thing4 = Thing(
            name: "Pride and Prejudice",
            comment: "A romance novel set in Regency England.",
            recordType: "Jane Austen",
            count: 5
        )
        
        let thing5 = Thing(
            name: "The Catcher in the Rye",
            comment: "A novel about teenage alienation.",
            recordType: "J.D. Salinger",
            count: 3
        )
        
        context.insert(thing1)
        context.insert(thing2)
        context.insert(thing3)
        context.insert(thing4)
        context.insert(thing5)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving data: \(error)")
        }
    }//create samples
    
}//struct

struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Put the regular welcome view here")
    }
}

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 16.1, iOS 18.1.

This isn't working because onAppear isn't called after ThingListView is rendered for the first time (i.e. it isn't called when navigating back to the app). If you fully quit the app and run your shortcut, you'll see that it now works (because then onAppear is actually called for the first time after you set your navigateToThingAddView flag inside the intent).
One quick fix would be to use the following instead:
.onChange(of: navigateToThingAddView) { _, newValue in
  if newValue {
    showThingAddView = true
    navigateToThingAddView = false
  }
}

I should note that this whole setup with @AppStorage and a boolean flag is a bit clunky. A better way to accomplish this would be to use @Dependency to pass navigation info – see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342508. You could also use onOpenURL (see the other answer on that same question). Both would allow you to navigate without a dummy flag stored in UserDefaults and without having to worry about setting that flag back to false.

Thanks. I will check out the @Dependency. I have not used that macro yet - good time to learn it.
